# UIToolbar with background colour clear turns white in iOS 10

Tags: swift, xcode7, uitoolbar, xcode-storyboard

I have a `UIView` inside which I added a `UIToolBar`.

I have given background colour as clear colour. It works fine in iOS 9 but in iOS 10 it changes to white. Any other colour than clear colour is working fine in iOS 10.

I am using Xcode 7.3, storyboard and swift.

Comment: which code have you tried?

Comment: @Rroobb no code, only in storyboard, Added a UIView. inside it dragged a UIToolBar and set its background colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
     @IBOutlet var mytab: UIToolbar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myImage = UIImage()


    mytab.setBackgroundImage(myImage, forToolbarPosition: .any, barMetrics: .default)
    mytab.isTranslucent = true

}
```

Comment: why view.backgroundColor?

Comment: your color of UIView

Comment: I have a image in the background, What I want is the UIToolBar to have no colour at all.

Comment: I'm glad I helped you

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why was it working in iOS 9 so far but not in iOS 10?

Comment: Really I don't know, I searched inside the apple forum and  documentation of UIToolbar. But I haven't found nothing.